# How do I use the NSString draw functionality to create a UIImage from text

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uiimage

I would like to draw the content of a `NSString` variable in a `UIImage`, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I need to write a method that would receive a `NSString` as parameter and return a `UIImage` with the text drawn into it.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can try this: (updated for iOS 4)

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text
{
    // set the font type and size
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];  
    CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:font];

    // check if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (iOS is 4.0+)
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);
    else
        // iOS is < 4.0 
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    // optional: add a shadow, to avoid clipping the shadow you should make the context size bigger 
    //
    // CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0), 5.0, [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]);

    // draw in context, you can use also drawInRect:withFont:
    [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];

    // transfer image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return image;
}
```

To call it:

```
UIImage *image = [self imageFromText:@"This is a text"];
```

Comment: for iOS4+ you should create the context with scaling 0.0 as to get the main screen's scaling if the scaling is not 1.0 (retina display is 2.0):  
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

Comment: @rpmx escape characters like \n new line are not getting detected??

Comment: @Yadnesh: Use: [text drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font] ;

Comment: How do you set the font color?

Comment: @PsychoDad you call -set on a UIColor before the [text drawAtPoint] line.  Something like this: [[UIColor redColor] set];

Comment: rpmx -- Great answers. Thanks for sharing. For anyone that finds this page and is targeting iOS 7, please note that the drawAtPoint:withFont method has been deprecated. So you need to make one small tweak to the above code - Change this: [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font]; TO THIS: [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 8.0) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];

Comment: Since sizeWithFont is now deprecated, replace first two lines with: UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Bold" size:15.0f];
 
 NSDictionary *attr = @{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
 CGSize size  = [text sizeWithAttributes:attr];

Answer (score 15):

Adding a Swift version, also gives you more options:

```
class func sizeOfAttributeString(str: NSAttributedString, maxWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    let size = str.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(maxWidth, 1000), options:(NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), context:nil).size
    return size
}

class func imageFromText(text:NSString, font:UIFont, maxWidth:CGFloat, color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    paragraph.alignment = .Center // potentially this can be an input param too, but i guess in most use cases we want center align

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraph])

    let size = sizeOfAttributeString(attributedString, maxWidth: maxWidth)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false , 0.0)
    attributedString.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Begin an image context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, draw to it, get an image with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, end it with `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`

Comment: How do I draw the NSString to it? That was what I was asking. PLEASE!

Comment: look at NSString UIKit Additions - there're multiple nsstring drawing functions available - like 'drawAtPoint:withFont:' or 'drawInRect:withFont:' and others

Comment: @Jaba: look at `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` and related functions.

Comment: Thank you so much I will research that.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.1**

```
func sizeOfAttributeString(str: NSAttributedString, maxWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    let size = str.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: 1000), options:(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), context:nil).size
    return size
}

func imageFromText(text:NSString, font:UIFont, maxWidth:CGFloat, color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    paragraph.alignment = .center 

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraph])

    let size = sizeOfAttributeString(str: attributedString, maxWidth: maxWidth)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false , 0.0)
    attributedString.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

Credit goes to Bao Lei for the beautiful answer.