# Insert text or Edit Image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing, edit, image-editing

I am stuck with this problem and not getting any idea about this.?

I do have some images in the application, and I want to insert some text in to that images which I take as input from the user?

I don't have any idea how to accomplish this task? Is it possible or not.

Basic Idea is : I do have images in to the application resources.
I want to insert text at certain place or at some cordinate.
Lets say, User insert: Merry Christmas, so the text get include in the image. at specific cordinate of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference 1](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx)

[How do I use the NSString draw functionality to create a UIImage from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765537/how-do-i-use-the-nsstring-draw-functionality-to-create-a-uiimage-from-text)

may help you a bit

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to save the images with text input by the user? If not not then you can simply add label on imageView

Comment: yeah obviously I want to save this image with its original dimensions..! thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think the best would be to save the screenshot of image with text.& renaming the existing the image with the same name as previous one