# Can a UILabel be part of a created image?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, draw

I have a project where I let the user draw on the screen of the iPhone (signature box).  It works great... prints to a specific label printer (Zebra gx420d).  My question is as follows:  Can I have a UILabel field be part of the "Image" that is drawn?  It is visible on screen, but doesn't print.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the label and your custom view subclass that draws the signature are both subviews of a common superview. Then invoke print on the common superview, and both of them (actually all subviews) will be part of the printed image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the text into an image graphics context.

This question may help: [How do I use the NSString draw functionality to create a UIImage from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765537/how-do-i-use-the-nsstring-draw-functionality-to-create-a-uiimage-from-text)