# NSString to UIImage drawing issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uiimage, drawing

I'm using this code to generate an UIImage from the text

[How do I use the NSString draw functionality to create a UIImage from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765537/how-do-i-use-the-nsstring-draw-functionality-to-create-a-uiimage-from-text)

However the image quality is very low. What parameters should I change to increase the quality of the image? is there a way to set resolution etc?

If anyone knows a good guide or documentation on this please provide a link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How low is it? Another way is to open a context, draw some text there, and then get image from context, it should work.. I would give you an example, but I don't have the code right now...

Comment: when i generate the image from iPhone retina simulator, it looks better. But with normal simulator quality is bit low. Increasing the font size did fix the issue for now. but is it a good practice? isn't there a way to set the image resolution etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the font size in that code. This will give a bigger image to start with, and might improve your experience.

Comment: increasing font size helped, but is it the only way of making image look better? increasing font size also increases the size of the UIImage. How can I draw this text in a 200x20px small image with best quality ? (without any pixelated edges)

Comment: What I'm suggesting you do is draw the text large and scale the resulting image down so that it fits in your 200x20px limit.

Comment: I'm surprised about the "pixelated edges". Perhaps the drawing is not antialiasing the text? You might try calling `CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, true)` in that code you cited.