# iOS UIView render to UIImage - Apple's sample code works only once

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

In my app i want to render the view of a UIView into a UIImage. I use apple's sample code for this, that can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

On the first try it works fine. But if later i modify a UILabel's text that's inside the view, the function above returns with the same image as it did the previous time.
I checked that label's text does actually change. But still the rendered image doesn't show the changes.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The Apple code is okay. Try searching your own code for issues. I can ask few questions to help you find your fault.

Maybe you are looking at the old image twice instead of setting new one correctly?
Maybe you are taking screenshot before the label text is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Me only suggestion in here is not to restoring the CGState in your code. That could be the problem ....

Maybe you can try to draw the nsstring into the Image and than collapse the images 
see this post [How to draw NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765537/how-do-i-use-the-nsstring-draw-functionality-to-create-a-uiimage-from-text)

But still my question is : 
How can you have more than one window within one app? 
Common use is to have one window and more views inside it... ? 
So why you need to use more windows ?

And another question is the last window you use also the one containing the text you want to display? Because you are retreiving the last window only .

Imagine U have 3 views:
One is black 
One is blue 
One is white

If you iterate over them and render them into layer and the last one is white -> you will get only the white one. Because the two others are rendered under the last one.

So is your window the top one?

Othewise I dont get it but definitely you can use this snippet

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You will be noticed that the instance method is not found, but it exists.

You will also need to import QuartzCore.

Comment: Hi! Thank for the long answer. However that code doesn't work either. I have several views because i only create a viewcontroller so i can export its layout to an image. the viewcontroller will never be visible. it gets created, modified, than deleted without ever being visible.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are modifying the UILabel's text property in main thread.

Halfar's answer looks right. Update on iOS 7 is there are also a new API to capture view's content, you may be interested to have a look at following snippet.

http://ioscodesnippet.com/2011/08/25/rendering-any-uiviews-into-uiimage-in-one-line/